# Get Auto-Brightness level

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I was wondering if there was a way to get the back-light or auto-brightness level of an iOS-device using the public frameworks.

Using UIScreen's **brightness** property simply gets the brightness level set by the user in System Preferences, which may be different than the auto-brightness level - in most cases, it is, which means that the aforementioned property does not auto-adjust if the auto-brightness switch (in System preferences) is turned on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you need to use the private API, or write your own classes o calculate the brightness from one of the cameras on the device.